# Py_BuildValue and PyArg_ParseTuple Seg fault

Tags: python, c++

EDIT: I was missing the `Py_Initialize()` at the beginning of the process.

I am experiencing some strange behavior with Py_BuildValue and PYArg_ParseTuple.

First, whenever I try to build an integer, I get a seg fault at Py_BuildValue.
This doesn't happen with floats, Objects, or strings.

Second, when I attempt to parse a tuple, I also get a seg fault unless I am parsing a tuple containing a single string: "s", or a single PyObject: "O". (I also get a segfault if I try to parse both together: "Os")

Here are two examples that segfault:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    Py_Initialize(); // <-- Missing this
    PyObject* pString = Py_BuildValue("s", "hello"); //<- Works fine
    PyObject* pFloat = Py_BuildValue("f", 2.3); //<- Works fine

    PyObject* pInt = Py_BuildValue("i", 2); // <- Seg faults

    return 0;
}
```

and an example with ParseTuple (Edited for correct buildvalue and tests on api calls):

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    Py_Initialize(); // <-- Missing this
    PyObject* pFloat = Py_BuildValue("f", 2.3);
    if(!pFloat)
        cout << "Error Float" << endl;

    PyObject *pTuple = PyTuple_New(1);
    if(!pTuple)
        cout << "Error Creating Tuple" << endl;

    if(PyTuple_SetItem(pTuple, 0, pFloat)) //Returns 0 on success
        cout << "Error Set Item" << endl;

    // parse tuple items
    float f;
    if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(pTuple, "f", &f))
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "invalid parameter");

    return 0;
}
```

I am running on RedHat with anaconda python 2.7

I compile with:

```
g++ `python-config --cflags` -L/home/user/anaconda/lib/ -lpython2.7 test.cpp -o test.out
```

Is it perhaps some problem with using anaconda python? I've broken the problem down to the simplest case I can come up with...

Comment: What happens when you change the *incorrect* `"2.3"` to `2.3`? (The `"f"` format needs a *double* not a string!).

Comment: ya, it still seg faults at the ParseTuple line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see a couple of issues.

The `f` option to `Py_BuildValue` constructs a Python float from a C/C++ `double`. You passed a string, not a double.

After every call to a Python C-API function, you need to test the return value to see if an error occurred. This needs to be done after every call.

Edit - one more issue.

When embedding Python C-API calls into a C/C++ program, the interpreter needs to be initialized with a call to `Py_Initialize()`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I made the changes. I was copy and pasting too much and forgot to remove the quotes from the 2.3. I edited the code above, but it is still seg faulting at the ParseTuple line... I also compiled a local copy of python to remove anaconda from the equation.

Comment: You also need to add a call to `Py_Initialize()`. I've edited the answer.

Comment: You are correct! That solved it. It is unfortunate that there are thousands of little tutorials online but none seem to mention this. Granted I guess most assume you are calling these functions from python, so you dont need to initialize the interpreter (correct?). Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are correct. I (and probably most users) write C/C++ that is called by Python. See https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html for the documentation for embedding Python into C/C++.